# Double underscore for Python method *argument*

Tags: python

I know what double underscore means for Python class attributes/methods, but does it mean something for method argument?

It looks like you cannot pass argument starting with double underscore to methods.  It is confusing because you can do that for normal functions.

Consider this script:

```
def egg(__a=None):
    return __a

print "egg(1) =",
print egg(1)
print


class Spam(object):

    def egg(self, __a=None):
        return __a

print "Spam().egg(__a=1) =",
print Spam().egg(__a=1)
```

Running this script yields:

```
egg(1) = 1

Spam().egg(__a=1) =
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/....py", line 15, in <module>
    print Spam().egg(__a=1)
TypeError: egg() got an unexpected keyword argument '__a'
```

I checked this with Python 2.7.2.

---

Some other examples

This works:

```
def egg(self, __a):
    return __a


class Spam(object):

    egg = egg

Spam().egg(__a=1)
```

This does not:

```
class Spam(object):

    def _egg(self, __a=None):
        return __a

    def egg(self, a):
        return self._egg(__a=a)

Spam().egg(1)
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Name mangling applies to all identifiers with leading double underscores, [regardless of where they occur](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers) (second to last sentence in that section):

> This transformation is independent of the syntactical context in which the identifier is used.

This is simpler to implement and to define, and more consistent. It may seem stupid, but the whole name mangling deal is an ugly little hack IMHO; and you're not expected to use names like that for anything except attributes/methods anyway.

`Spam().egg(_Spam__a=1)`, as well as `Spam().egg(1)`, does work. But even though you can make it work, leading underscores (any number of them) have no place in parameter names. Or in any local variable (exception: `_`) for that matter.

**Edit:** You appear to have found a corner case nobody ever considered. The documentation is imprecise here, or the implementation is flawed. It appears keyword argument names are not mangled. Look at the bytecode (Python 3.2):

```
>>> dis.dis(Spam.egg)
  3           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (_egg)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('__a') # keyword argument not mangled
              9 LOAD_FAST                1 (a)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION          256
             15 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(Spam._egg)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                1 (_Spam__a) # parameter mangled
              3 RETURN_VALUE
```

This may be rooted in the fact that keyword arguments are equivalent to passing a dict (in this case `{'__a': 1}`) whose keys wouldn't be mangled either. But honestly, I'd just call it an ugly corner case in an already ugly special case and move on. It's not important because you shouldn't use identifiers like that anyway.

Comment: If it happens "regardless of where they occur", I expect the last example (the one I added) works.  I guess I know why it doesn't though; it should be in "class namespace" or something like that (I don't know what is the right word for that), right?

Comment: I'd expect that too, and am quite surprised. I guess it's a flaw in either the documentation or the implementation. I'm editing right now to add my findings.

Comment: I agree that it's not elegant parameter, but consider when you have something like `self.__dict__.update(kwds)` in the function but want to control the behavior of the function.  The only valid argument name I can think of to control the behavior is the one starts with double underscore.

Comment: @tkf How about a positional parameter? Single underscores should also be okay since those aren't common either, but I'd argue that it's very important to keep the controlling parameters and the kwargs as different as possible so the reader can easily distinguish them.

Answer (score 3):

It gets converted to `_Spam__a`:

```
In [20]: class Spam(object):
   ....:     
   ....:         def egg(self, __a=None):
   ....:             return __a
   ....: 

In [21]: Spam.egg.__func__.__code__.co_varnames
Out[21]: ('self', '_Spam__a')
```

Answer (score 1):

Double Underscore or [Name Mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Name_mangling_in_Python) in a class context is a private identifier. In your example try dir(Spam.egg) and you will see that the parameter __a is now `_Spam__egg`.

You can now use:

```
Spam().egg(_Spam__a=1)
```