# Python3 kwarg starting with dunder not possible in classes & private attributes generated by dataclasses

Tags: python-3.x, python-dataclasses

I'm a bit confused by the following behavior (in Python 3.9):

```py
class Dunder:
    def __init__(self, __a_kwarg="hello"):
        self.__a_kwarg = __a_kwarg
        print(self.__a_kwarg)

Dunder(__a_kwarg="Hello world")
```

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__a_kwarg'
```

But if I do:

```py
class Dunder:
    def __init__(self, __a_kwarg="hello"):
        self.__a_kwarg = __a_kwarg
        print(self.__a_kwarg)

Dunder("Hello world")
```

```
"Hello world"
```

The first argument gets assigned to the first parameter, as expected and everything works just fine.

Using a normal function also works as expected:

```py
def fn(__a_kwarg="hello"):
    print(__a_kwarg)

fn(__a_kwarg="Hello world")
```

```
"Hello world"
```

I suspect that it has something to do with "dunder" hinting to private variables. But why shouldn't it be possible to address a kwarg with double-underscores?

Searching the web I found that issue from MyPy [issues/5156](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/5156) but this does not provide an answer to my question.

I am doing this because I want to have `dataclass` with a private attribute that has a default value and my IDE (PyCharm) suggested that I can address this parameter as a kwarg (which would be great since there are multiple optional parameters), but Python said no.

A snippet from my actual code:

```
@dataclass
class Incident(JsonDumpable):
    """ Class representing a single incident"""

    id_: Union[incident_id, float]
    __timeout_s: int
    __response: IncidentResponse = IncidentResponse.NoResponse
    active: bool = True


Incident(
    loaded_dict["id"],
    loaded_dict["timeout_s"],
    __response=IncidentResponse.get_enum(loaded_dict["response"]),
    active=loaded_dict["active"],
                    )
```

Alternatively, how else can I solve my "private-parameter with kwarg in dataclass" problem? I already know that `__post_init__` is a thing, there I could introduce my private "copy", but how do I get rid of the non-private version created by the dataclass (in a way that PyCharm gets that this attribute is deleted)?

Comment: In Python 3.10.9 and 3.11.1 I get consistent behaviour between the two class implementations, `TypeError: Dunder.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument '__a_kwarg'`. Seems to be a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/12517877/3001761; `Dunder(_Dunder__a_kwarg="Hello world")` works fine.

Comment: Damn. That's from python2 times. Yeah. It's the same question.
So the problem seems to be that python does its "hiding" of private variables also for the signature of a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"__ " as a variable or attribute prefixes triggers a name-mangling feature of Python, and that is *not* referred as "private attributes"  in the language docs. Python does *not* have private attributes, its O.O. model is based on the premise of "consenting adults": one SINGLE "_" to mean that attribute should not be fiddled with from 3rdy party code.

"__ " prefixes implements a very practical aspect of "private" attributes which is to avoid attribute name collision in large inheritance hierarchies - and should not be used by people. The "__" prefix in your parameter name in the method is changed at compile time - so that other methods in the class using the same name will be able to reach it, but anything outside the class, (such as your code trying to instantiate the class and pass it as a named argument), will have to perform the name-mangling manually to match what is created internally.  The transformation for that is easy: a "_" prefix + class_name + original_name - so writing `fn(_Dunder__a_kwarg="Hello world")` would work - but you will make your life easier if you simply to not attempt to do that.

Just use plain single underline prefixes, "_ " to indicate private attributes and you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer why it doesn't work. The question *why* it is implemented that way is an other question...

```py
import inspect


class Dunder:
    def __init__(self, __a_kwarg="hello"):
        print(self.__a_kwarg)

print(inspect.signature(Dunder.__init__))

Dunder(_Dunder__a_kwarg="Hello world")
```

```
(self, _Dunder__a_kwarg='hello')
Hello world
```

So it turns out that python really mangles ("hides") the kwarg when starting with "dunder".

`__a_kwarg` becomes `_Dunder__a_kwarg` and you can address the "new" kwarg as you're used to.

Im referencing the source in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#atom-identifiers), which was mentioned in the related question here too.